# How to get the raw byte from a unicode char?

Tags: python, unicode

```
>>> u'\u6162'
u'\u6162'
```

For the above unicode char (I assume `0x62` should be in its lower bits. Correct me if I am wrong), I'd like to get a list of its raw bytes (ASCII `0x62` corresponds to `b`). Could anybody show me how to do it in both python2 and 3 (if the code is different)? Thanks.

```
['b', 'a']
```

Comment: Just curious on how you ended up with an unicode string with such content. Or is it really chinese text?

Comment: There are no bytes; that's the integer code point for the single Unicode character `慢`. Bytes only become relevant if you *encode* it using UTF-8, UTF-16, or something similar.

Comment: @chepner That is probably what they meant. Using UTF-32 you should be able to see that

Comment: Actually for below BMP you might be able to use UTF-16 for that purpose 99% of the time

Comment: @JBernardo What exactly do you mean? All UTF-[8, 16, 32] cover the entire unicode character set.

Comment: @schwobaseggl But in different manners. You would want to have the output to have fixed amount of bytes instead of surrogate pairs

Comment: @JBernardo I just made the character up.

Answer (score 0):

It would be safer to use UTF-32 because it covers the whole BMP plane with the same amount of bytes. That way you get 2 extra `\x00` bytes that are easily removed.

```
>>> u'\u6162'.encode('utf-32le')
b'ba\x00\x00'
```

If you know you won't have weird chars that would use more than 2 bytes on UTF-16, you can use it too:

```
>>> u'\u6162'.encode('utf-16le')
b'ba'
```

Note I'm using `le` variants of the encoders to not add BOM and to have the desired byte order. If you rather have `ab` instead, use `be` variant (e.g. `'utf-16be'`).

That code works both on Python 2 and 3, but notice byte strings on Python 3 behave differently.

More useful info on difference on encodings:
https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode_encodings.html

Comment: I just realize it will not work something like this `'á'.encode('utf-16le')`. I probably should ask for an int array `[0x62, 0x61]`? Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @user1424739 You have exactly that on Python 3. if you do `list(b'ba')` you get just that. On Python2 you need something like `[ord(c) for c in b'ba')`

Comment: No. The starting point is `u'\u6162'` not `b'ba'`. It should also work for thing that can not fit in ASCII (e.g., <128).

Comment: Actually, it does work fine with `u'á'` (at least that result is what I expect). Anything below 2 bytes will be that same byte plus `\x00`. Each byte is the equivalent of a latin-1 encoding

Comment: I meant `list(u'\u6162'.encode('utf-16le'))`... which is the same as `list(b'ba')`.

Comment: Why does `u'a'.encode('utf-16le')` have an `\x00` at the end, but `u'\u6162'.encode('utf-16le')` does not. When a null char will be added at the end?

Comment: @user1424739 For x < 256 it will use the equivalent of `latin-1` encoding which has the `á` char. The reason UTF-8 is different is because it can only support x < 127 before moving on to multiple bytes output

Comment: So when x < 256, a null char will be appended at the end? For any other x, there will be no null char appended?

Comment: I don't know what are you doing but for ANY char you input, you will get 4 bytes on utf-32le or 2 bytes on utf-16le (may have edge cases, but never less than 2)... I advise you to use `utf-32be` since it will be a bunch of zeros and then the relevant data. If in doubt, just test it and see what you get. This is quite straightforward